# Book series about colonization and migration into space

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a series of novels in the 1990s-2000s where a world was colonized from Earth by slower than light travel. Eventually, FTL travel was invented and the world changed dramatically (I remember there were camps where living conditions were poor). I seem to remember that there was sabotage of a ring that was being constructed that would have led to even more migration. I’ve been looking for the series for years. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: In order for us to better aid you, can you look through the questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info? Edit the answers to as many of those as you can into your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like the *[Coyote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote_(Steele_novel))* Series by Allen Steele. The first colonists are political refugees from North America they travel using cyrostasis in a slower than light vessel. The second group is a government funded expedition using a FTL dilation drive of some kind, different government to that fled by group one (I think they're from Latin America) but they treat both the "natives" and their own new colonists poorly and are ousted. The ring is for instantaneous travel between Coyote and Earth and is initially resisted by the population on Coyote, it does get built eventually under treaty with a third government group from Europe. There are three or four books set on Coyote and several other novels set in the same universe.

Comment: Sure sounds like Coyote, but the second group didn't have FTL merely the ability to go at a much faster speed than the first.  They left MUCH later and arrived only a few years later, due to time dilation.  The original colonists used a ship called The Alabama and were fleeing from a right-wing dictatorship called "The United Republic of America".  The second group had a system that I call "Communism 2.0".  (Not an improvement over the original.)  I add these details just to maybe trigger an "Oh, yeah".

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt Thanks for that, I haven't read _Coyote_ or _Coyote Rising_ for years.

Comment: That’s it!!!! Thank you!!!! I have been looking for this for years!